# What was Weyland suffering from?

Tags: prometheus

In [Prometheus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prometheus_%28film%29#Plot), it is shown in 2089, Dr. Shaw and Dr. Holloway discovered another cave-drawing of so-called engineers. In 2093, they reached LV-223. They have been asleep for two years (The geologist told the biologist `I have been asleep two years`) . That concludes both the doctors met Weyland in 2091. But when Weyland had told in the video `And I am long dead` in the ship, nobody became surprised.

So was Weyland expected to be dead by that time? What happened to him? Was he suffering from some sort of disease? Or he was very old and that is why everybody thought he might have been dead. It seemed that the crew knew that Weyland was going to die very soon. Holloway said ,“Wow! Never taken orders from a ghost before.”, Who met Weyland himself. I did not understand that part.

Comment: He says "I've never *followed* a ghost before." "Followed" in the showbiz sense, like tough act to follow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cause of Weyland's alleged death is never revealed in the movie -- but **whatever the cause of the alleged death, his entrance later suggests he was lying in the hologram, intending to convince the hologram's viewers that he would be dead well before 
2093**.

The motive behind this lying is also not revealed in the movie (though it is [discussed on StackExchange](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2846/why-does-weyland-have-to-hide-that-he-was-on-the-ship)).